# Bootstrap 4 styling only left column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a row filled dynamically with X items contained in col-3 class (depending on the actual screen size).

Is it possible to stylized easily only the column that will appear on left during a screen resizing?

Like this: 
`lg` screen:
[image: lg view]

`md` screen:

[image: md view]

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="box">Box 9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve the result with [`:nth-of-type(n)`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) selector with some media queries. For example

```
// lg
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) { 
    div.yourClass:nth-of-type(4n-3){
        color:green;
        // or whatever css you want
    }
}

// md
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { 
    div.yourClass:nth-of-type(3n-2){
        color:green;
        // or whatever css you want
    }
}
```

**Sample (go full page)**

```css
.rectangle {
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  div.rectangle:nth-of-type(4n-3) {
    border-color: green;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  div.rectangle:nth-of-type(3n-2) {
    border-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j67Lkxas/)

**Drawback**

The drawback for this is that you would need to know exactly how many elements will be present in a single line for each screen size and need custom css for each

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this selector. Looks like working there: https://jsfiddle.net/kr1zwt0g/7/ 

But yes it needs to be set for each screen but better than nothing, (I will let open the question to see if someone knows another solution maybe).

Comment: 15 days after, still not a new answer, I will set your as the one that solved my problem. Thank you again @arun-a-s